# Best way to create n objects in another class' constructor?

Tags: c++, dynamic, constructor

I wanted to create a variable amount of Treasure objects when a chest object is created. This is the solution I came up with. To create an array of n Treasures, later to be parsed as needed. Room for improvement?

```
Chest::Chest (int n) {

Treasure * tArr = new Treasure[n];

}
```

Each treasure has a unique ID, and is then parsed into a map, mapping int ID to Treasure.

Comment: *"Room for improvement?"* Use `std::vector`?

Comment: If you want to later parse it, you need to store it's size somehow. You also have to implement the assignment operators, the copy and move constructor and the destructor correctly. It's probably easier to just use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Level 0 improvement: avoid loosing the objects you've created

Your variable `tArr` is a local object of the constructor and will be lost when the construction is over, leading to memory leaks.

So if you want this code to be useful, you'll need to make `tArr` a member variable and avoid redefining it in the constructor.

```
Chest::Chest (int n) {
    tArr = new Treasure[n];    // assuming Treasure *tArr is a class variable
}
```

#### Level 1 improvement: the rule of 3

The first improvement would be implement the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).  Otherwise, you'll quickly run into nasty troubles, if for example by accident you'd copy a `Chest`.

#### Level 2 improvement: forget about arrays and use vectors

Arrays are medieval ages to C++.  Use [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
class Chest {
    std::vector<Treasure> tArr;     // naming could be discussed...
    ...
}; 

Chest::Chest (int n) : tArr(n) {    // construct the vector with n elements
               // now do whatever you want with these elements
}
```

Now the cool thing with vector is that they can grow dynamically.  So you could start with an empty vector and add new treasures using [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

```
Treasure x(...); // create a cool treasure not just default initialized 
tArr.push_back(x);  // add it at the end of the vector
```

This could allow you for example in your constructor to add random treasures, if uniform treasures are too boring.

But you could as well [`resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) it on the flow to an arbitrary value:

```
tArr.resize(tArr.size()*2);   // two times more treasures !!!
```

#### Level 3 improvement:  use a map

The following intent is not totally clear:

> Each treasure has a unique ID, and is then parsed into a map, mapping
>   int ID to Treasure.

Assuming ID is sequential and local to the `Chest`, the vector is all you need:  the index will be the ID.

If however the ID is not sequential, or not local to the Chest, you may be interested in a [map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), which is a kind of associative array:

```
std::map<int, Treasure> myMap;  // maps an int ID to a Treasure.
```

The problem is that you cannot just create an map with n elements in it:  you need to add the elements one by one:

```
myMap[id] = Treasure(...);      // changes the element with id, or creates it
```

Cector is much simpler.  So go for a map only if it's really justified.